# Identification of Seaplane Type

Tags: identification, aircraft

[image]

Nothing included on this old photograph other than it is a seaplane. Is it possible to know the manufacturer and where it was flown?

Comment: Do we know the source of the image? How did you obtain the image?

Comment: I purchased this in a group of old photos on ebay. There are several other bi-plane pictures in the group. None of them have any information associated with them.

Answer (score 10):

I believe what you have would be a [Curtis HS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_HS) model, possible the HS-1, or more probably the HS-2L.

> The Curtiss HS was a single-engined patrol flying boat built for the
>   United States Navy during World War I. Large numbers were built from
>   1917 to 1919, with the type being used to carry out anti-submarine
>   patrols from bases in France from June 1918. It remained in use with
>   the US Navy until 1928, and was also widely used as a civil passenger
>   and utility aircraft

The smaller HS-1:
[image]

Yours seems to have some differences from the one pictures above,such as a larger wingspan, but I think its probably a similar model, perhaps earlier.  These planes (actually called [flying boats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_boat)) were from the World War 1 era.

...and the HS-2L(as noted in comments-longer wingspan, more  closely resembles the above photo)

> Curtiss produced an increased-span version, the HS-2 with span
>   increased by 12 ft (3.66 m) and an additional set of interplane
>   struts, giving four-bay wings rather than the three-bay wings of the
>   HS-1L

[image]

More info on civilian use of one HS-2L after the war:

- [CURTISS HS-2L LA VIGILANCE](http://casmuseum.techno-science.ca/en/collection-research/artifact-curtiss-hs-2l-la-vigilance.php)

Comment: In the photograph provided, there are four vertical reinforcements on both the left and right side of the wings. Thus, the plane in the photograph is a Curtis HS-2L, no the HS-1

Comment: Agree, updated answer with second model.